# Upload image with react native to S3

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, api-gateway

I have an app that works with react native, it handles image and video which I want to upload to an S3 bucket, if I install @aws-sdk/client-s3 it uses node modules which do not work in react native, I get an error with "stream ", there is no concrete solution that helps me with that and seeing in other forums no one has been able to solve that, any idea on how I could upload my photos and videos to the bucket, I have an api with express framework but the problem is that I do code base64 or anything else exceeds the megabyte limit, any idea what I can do?

I am not choosing to use something like multer or expand the megabyte limit of express since the API receives several requests and we do not want all those files that are being uploaded in the API to be created on disk, I was perhaps thinking of using Api Gateway and creating An API that will handle the upload directly to the S3 bucket (use the integration option with other AWS services) and send it to call to upload all the content, is this a good option or how could I solve this?

Comment: Please Add Some Code or example that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. I did the following steps to solve it.

1. `npm i readable-stream react-native-url-polyfill react-native-get-random-values`
2. Added this in metro.config.js

   resolver: {
   extraNodeModules: {
   stream: require.resolve('readable-stream'),
   }
   }
3. In the file where I have the S3 upload function, Add these imports
   `import 'react-native-get-random-values'; import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';`

Comment: The "stream" error disappeared but now I have this one, **Android Bundling failed 15259ms
The package at "node_modules\@smithy\util-stream\dist-cjs\sdk-stream-mixin.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util".**

Comment: Go to `node_modules > @smithy > util-stream > package.json` and replace `"main": "./dist-cjs/index.js"` with `"main": "./dist-es/index.js",`

Comment: It works now, thanks, I hope this post helps other people solve the same error **(I've seen several with the same problem)**